# problema con ajax en la respuesta del servidor en la función success. Ayuda, gracias

Tags: jquery, ajax

tengo un problema con ajax:NO obtengo respuesta del servidor y en la cónsola no me sale nada. Inserta en la base datos pero no ejecuta la respuesta del success. (éste fichero es registro.php)

$("#registro").submit(function(e){

```
if($("#altausua").val()!="" && $("#altacontra").val()!="" && $("#altacontra2").val()!=""){ //para que funcione el validate

    var altausua=$("#altausua").val();//cogemos el valor de los campos
    var altacontra=$("#altacontra").val();      

                    $("#dadobaja").hide("slow");//oculta los alert
                    $("#noexiste").hide("slow");
                    $("#correcto").hide("slow");
                    $("#yaexiste").hide("slow");
                    $("#bienvenido").hide("slow");
                    $("#carga").show("fast");

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",//tipo de envío
        url:"../controlador/controlador.php",//ruta a donde va
        data:{altausua:altausua, altacontra:altacontra},//asociamos las variables a campos
        beforeSend:function(){//antes de enviar los datos hace esto
                    $("#dadobaja").hide("slow");//oculta los alert
                    $("#noexiste").hide("slow");
                    $("#correcto").hide("slow");
                    $("#yaexiste").hide("slow");
                    $("#bienvenido").hide("slow");
                    $("#carga").show("fast");//muestra la carga
                    },
        success:function(datdevuelto){
                    if(datdevuelto.match("Registradocorrectamente")){
                        $("#carga").hide("fast");//que oculte la carga      
                        $("#registro").hide();
                        location.href="registro.php?alert=3";//añadido correctamente
                    }else{
                        $("#carga").hide("fast");//que oculte la carga
                        location.href="registro.php?alert=4";//el usuario ya existe

                    }
                }//cierre de success            
    });//cierre de ajax 
}//cierre de la validación/}
```

});//cierre de submit

la evaluación del servidor:(este fichero es manejaObjetos.php)
//---------------- INSERTA USUARIOS NUEVOS -------------------------------------------------------

public function insertaUsuarios(ObjLogueo $log){

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM logueo WHERE NOMBRE= :usu";

$resultado1=$this->conexion->prepare($sql1);
$resultado1->bindValue(':usu', $log->getNombres());
$resultado1->execute();
$confirm=$resultado1->rowCount();

if($confirm==0 && $log->getNombres()!=""){//si no existe el usuario y el campo nombre no está vacío lo inserta
    $sql2="INSERT INTO logueo(NOMBRE, CONTRA) VALUES('" . $log->getNombres() . "','" . $log->getContra() . "')" ;

    $this->conexion->exec($sql2);

    echo "Registradocorrectamente";
    //header("location:../vista/registro.php?alert=3");
}else{
    echo "noregistro";
    //header("location:../vista/registro.php?alert=4");
    }
}
```

el controlador:(este fichero es controlador.php)

//-------------------INSERTA  NUEVO LOGUIN----------------------------------------------------------
if(isset($_POST['altausua'])){
    $ObjManeja2=new ManejaObjetos($conexion);//para inserta usuarios

```
$objLogin=new ObjLogueo();

$usuario=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['altausua']),ENT_QUOTES);
//$objLogin->setNombres(htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['usua'])));
$objLogin->setNombres($usuario);
$pass_cifrado=password_hash($_POST['altacontra'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$objLogin->setContra($pass_cifrado);

$ObjManeja2->insertaUsuarios($objLogin);
```

}

Comment: en tu ajax manda la propiedad `error: function (jqXHR, exception) {` para ver que esta pasando...

Answer (score 0):

encontré la solución. No se debe enviar con submit sinó con button y todo funciona perfecto menos el validate que hay que añadir una función debajo de validate :
$('#nombrebotón').on('click', function() {
    $("#nombreformulario").valid();
});